# rlang::expr() and rlang::eval() and database objects

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, duckdb

I'm writing a custom function that essentially:

1. Filter dataset by input args
2. summarizes by input selection
3. aggregates by a user selected scalar function (eg. min, max, sum)
4. pivots wider based on the inputs args

I can get it to work for a tibble or dataframe however when I use this against a database object (I've used a duckdb object below but I guess I actually want to stimulate a snowflake connection) it doesn't work.

Any suggestions to fix the error

```
library(tidyverse)


# this is the function

calculate <- function(.data,.fn,var,rows,cols,...){

  expr_fn=rlang::expr(.fn)
  expr_filter=rlang::expr(...)

  .data %>%
    filter(eval(expr_filter)) %>%
    group_by(pick({{rows}}),pick({{cols}}))%>%
    summarise(out=eval(expr_fn)({{var}}))%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from={{cols}},values_from = out)


}


# This works
calculate(diamonds,.fn=min,var=carat,rows=c(cut,color),cols=clarity,color=="D" & cut=="Fair")

# set up to create sample database object
conn_db <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())

duckdb::duckdb_register(conn_db,"diamonds_db",diamonds)

diamonds_db <- tbl(conn_db,"diamonds_db")

## this doesn't work
calculate(diamonds_db,.fn=min,var=carat,rows=c(cut,color),cols=clarity,color=="D" & cut=="Fair")
```